# Write query in CriteriaBuilder using Optional<T>

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, repository, option-type

```
@Query(value = "select usd from UserDetail usd where usd.phoneNumber=:phoneNumber")
Optional<UserDetail> findByPhoneNumber(@Valid @Param("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber);
```

This is my JPQL query method and I am here using return type with `Optional`. I wonder how to write using `CriteriaBuilder`?

I wrote like this but I am getting an error.

```java
@Override
public Optional<UserDetail> findByCreatedDate(String phoneNumber) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserDetail> cq = cb.createQuery(UserDetail.class);
    Root<UserDetail> root = cq.from(UserDetail.class);
    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("phoneNumber"), phoneNumber))
      .orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("phoneNumber")));
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList().get(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the method return type is `Optional` that is what exactly you must return.

The line `em.createQuery(cq).getResultList().get(3)` returns only `UserDetail` so you need to wrap it to `Optional.of`:

```java
@Override
public Optional<UserDetail> findByCreatedDate(String phoneNumber) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserDetail> cq = cb.createQuery(UserDetail.class);
    Root<UserDetail> root = cq.from(UserDetail.class);
    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("phoneNumber"), phoneNumber))
      .orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("phoneNumber")));
    return Optional.of(em.createQuery(cq).getResultList().get(3));
}
```

By the way, are you sure the hardcoded `.get(3)` is what you want? If the list is empty or has less than 4 elements, it would throw a runtime exception.

Comment: My UserDetail table have 4 column, id, created_date, phone_number,text_message. How to write witout hardcode, which I want column?

Answer (score 0):

if a phone number is associated with only one person why are you trying to get a list ?

have a look to this :

```
@Override
        public Optional<UserDetail> findByCreatedDate(String phoneNumber) {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<UserDetail> cq = cb.createQuery(UserDetail.class);
            Root<UserDetail> root = cq.from(UserDetail.class);
            cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("phoneNumber"), phoneNumber)).orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("phoneNumber")));
            UserDetail ud = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
            return ud == null ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(ud)
    
        }
```

Regards,

Comment: I do not receive a list, I want to get all the information of the man by phone number.

Comment: Hi, by calling `getResultList()` you get a list, look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#getResultList--).  By doing `em.createQuery(cq)` => the jpa api creates a `TypedQuery<UserDetail>` that encompasses the UserDetail object.
If you only want to select specific columns, you can use `em.createQuery(cq).multiSelect("column1", "column2")`, for this you will need a corresponding constructor for the selected columns in your object.